# How to retrieve the Project Key by Project Id programmatically in Jira?

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I need to get the project key (or keys) programmatically.

The only alternative to retrieve the project keys I found was the content on this page:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Editing+a+Project+Key#EditingaProjectKey-Notesfordevelopers

There it says:

- Get all project keys: com.atlassian.jira.project.ProjectManager#getAllProjectKeys

What I need is to retrieve the key(s) by project id.

Is there an easy way to do this? How can I know which key correspond to which project id?

I'm using Jira version 6.4.3 and Atlassian Plugin SDK version 5.0.13.

I am using the SAL Services. Is there any better option?.

Comment: If you set up a webhook to fire on creation / updated you can then deserialize the Json Payload that is sent to the URL endpoint, then display the Project Key, I don't know any to get all project keys at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no direct method to get keys with id but you can get Project object with id ad then you can get the project key from Project object

if you want to get project object for a id then try with 
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/project/ProjectManager.html#getProjectObj(java.lang.Long)

if you want to get Project objects for multiple project id's then try with this
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/project/ProjectManager.html#convertToProjectObjects(java.util.Collection)

i hope the above links will help you!!

Comment: I couldn't find this method before because I was using the "com.atlassian.sal.api.ProjectManager" class that, in spite of having the same name, doesn't have the method with the Project ID param. The class @Ram suggested have the method I need.